# Как при смене вкладки обнулить setBadgeText?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Мне нужно, чтобы если я акцентирую внимание на другой вкладке (не на той, где сработало расширение) текста над иконкой не было. Возвращаем фокус - номер (текст) тот, что был.
То есть чтобы Badge Text срабатывал только там.

Comment: переформулировать можете? Или подробней расписать. Я честно говоря не совсем понял чего вы хотите.

Comment: На одной вкладке мы нашли что-то, число изменилось, например, на 3 - щелкаем на другую, ранее открытую, там эта тройка остается. А должно быть 0, соответственно, на этой другой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> На одной вкладке мы нашли что-то, число изменилось

Так как более ничего не сказано, в качестве условия использовалась проверка равенства `URL` вкладки определенному значению.

---

Используем событие `chrome.tabs.onActivated`, которое срабатывает при смене активной вкладки и событие `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`, которое срабатывает при обновлении.

Кроме того, нужен метод `chrome.tabs.get`, который извлекает информацию о вкладке по ее идентификатору.

---

Пример использования:

```
function changeBadgeText(tabId, tabUrl) {

    // Если условие выполняется, установим значение равное 3 иначе 0
    var value = (tabUrl == "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/") ? "3" : "0";

    // Устанавливаем значение бейджу. Идентификатор указаывается в качестве ограничителя.
    // Т.е для вкладок подходящих под условие значение 3, а для всех остальных 0
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: value, tabId: tabId});
}

function changeBadgeTextOnActivated(tabInfo) {

    chrome.tabs.get(tabInfo.tabId, function (tab) {

        // Если поле url имеет значение, т.е вкладка загружена.
        // В ином случае данные будут получены из метода changeBadgeTextOnUpdate
        if (tab.url) changeBadgeText(tab.id, tab.url);
    });
}

function changeBadgeTextOnUpdate(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

    // Если страница загруженна. Допустим мы не переключали вкладки, а обновили открытую
    if (changeInfo.status == "complete") changeBadgeText(tabId, tab.url);
}

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(changeBadgeTextOnActivated);

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(changeBadgeTextOnUpdate);
```

---

Обратите внимание на особенность события `chrome.tabs.onActivated`:

> Note that the tab's URL may not be set at the time this event fired,
>   but you can listen to onUpdated events to be notified when a URL is
>   set.

---

[chrome.tabs.get](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-get) | [chrome.tabs.onActivated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) | [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated)

Comment: Спасибо, почти то, что нужно. Единственный минус - срабатывает лишь после переключения на другую вкладку. То есть переключаемся, возвращаемся - и значение применяется.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, без конкретных условий сложно разговаривать. Исходя из вышенаписанного я подготовил ответ. Я так понял,что проблема с установкой значений при переключении, т.е некое начальное уже стоит. Я же не знаю по какому условию вы значения устанавливаете. А про обновление я добавил - что в случае только что открывшихся вкладок или обновляемых нужно использовать `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`. Добавлю об этом подробней

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, обновил. Теперь сработает даже если вкладки не переключались, например при обновлении или открытие вкладки. Теперь все как надо?

Comment: Да, спасибо - то, что нужно!